YouTube upload always fails with "youtubeSignupRequired"
I've read through other posts with similar issues but I've hit a brick wall with Google APIs. Here's the situation:

I have a YouTube channel since 5 years ago, created from my personal Google account. It's for an audio podcast I'm recording. The YouTube channel is now a "brand account" apparently.
Now I'm trying to automatically upload the backlog of episodes, converted to videos, and automate future uploads.
After days of fiddling around with setting up a GCP project to allow this, the suggestion from some Google support bot was to create an organisation to avoid making the project public. I need a long-lived OAuth2 token here to make the automatisation worthwhile.
I created an organisation, which looks very much like a Google Workspace but is somehow different, and have 1 account there. I've added this account as an Owner to the YouTube channel. The new account can successfully manage the YouTube channel (30 days have passed since its creation - that's also a weird requirement).
I can successfully log in with this account in the backend Python script. Permitted domains, Oauth2 callbacks, etc. looks to be set up ok. Scopes are ok ("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.upload", "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.force-ssl")
Still, when I try to upload a video, Google bombs out with:

b'{\n  "error": {\n    
"code": 401,\n    
"message": "Unauthorized",\n    
"errors": [\n      {\n        
"message": "Unauthorized",\n        
"domain": "youtube.header",\n        
"reason": "youtubeSignupRequired",\n        
"location": "Authorization",\n        
"locationType": "header"\n
}\n    ]\n  }\n}\n'

What frustrates any debugging is that even though it errors out in this way, apparently in the Authorization stage, the call is still counted against the quota! I can only do 2-3 of those calls a day!
Is there way to make YouTube uploads work from a script?
EDIT: per commentator's request, here's the login script, it writes the client_credentials.json file after login:
import argparse
import httplib2
import json
import os, os.path
import pprint
import random
import time

import google.oauth2.credentials
import google_auth_oauthlib.flow
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from googleapiclient.errors import HttpError
from googleapiclient.http import MediaFileUpload
from google_auth_oauthlib.flow import InstalledAppFlow
from google.auth import external_account_authorized_user

# Explicitly tell the underlying HTTP transport library not to retry, since
# we are handling retry logic ourselves.
httplib2.RETRIES = 1

# Maximum number of times to retry before giving up.
MAX_RETRIES = 10

# Always retry when these exceptions are raised.
RETRIABLE_EXCEPTIONS = (
    httplib2.HttpLib2Error,
    IOError,
)

# Always retry when an apiclient.errors.HttpError with one of these status
# codes is raised.
RETRIABLE_STATUS_CODES = [500, 502, 503, 504]


CLIENT_SECRETS_FILE = "client_secrets.json"
CLIENT_CREDENTIALS_FILE = "client_credentials.json"

SCOPES = ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.upload", "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.force-ssl"]
API_SERVICE_NAME = "youtube"
API_VERSION = "v3"


# Authorize the request and store authorization credentials.
def get_authenticated_service():
    if not os.path.exists(CLIENT_CREDENTIALS_FILE):
        flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(CLIENT_SECRETS_FILE, SCOPES)
        credentials = flow.run_local_server(open_browser=False, port=8000, host='surovestrasti.com')
        credentials_json = credentials.to_json().replace('token_uri', 'token_url')
        #print(credentials_json)
        open(CLIENT_CREDENTIALS_FILE, 'wt').write(credentials_json)
    else:
        raise Exception("Please delete the client credentials file %s" % CLIENT_CREDENTIALS_FILE)
    return build(API_SERVICE_NAME, API_VERSION, credentials=credentials)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    youtube = get_authenticated_service()
    print("Logged in and stored credentials into %s" % CLIENT_CREDENTIALS_FILE)

And here's the YouTube upload script:

import argparse
import httplib2
import json
import os, os.path
import pprint
import random
import time

import google.oauth2.credentials
import google_auth_oauthlib.flow
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from googleapiclient.errors import HttpError
from googleapiclient.http import MediaFileUpload
from google_auth_oauthlib.flow import InstalledAppFlow
from google.auth import external_account_authorized_user

# Explicitly tell the underlying HTTP transport library not to retry, since
# we are handling retry logic ourselves.
httplib2.RETRIES = 1

# Maximum number of times to retry before giving up.
MAX_RETRIES = 10

# Always retry when these exceptions are raised.
RETRIABLE_EXCEPTIONS = (
    httplib2.HttpLib2Error,
    IOError,
)

RETRIABLE_STATUS_CODES = [500, 502, 503, 504]

CLIENT_SECRETS_FILE = "client_secrets.json"
CLIENT_CREDENTIALS_FILE = "client_credentials.json"

# This OAuth 2.0 access scope allows an application to upload files to the
# authenticated user's YouTube channel, but doesn't allow other types of access.
SCOPES = ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.upload", "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.force-ssl"]
API_SERVICE_NAME = "youtube"
API_VERSION = "v3"

VALID_PRIVACY_STATUSES = ("public", "private", "unlisted")


# Authorize the request and store authorization credentials.
def get_authenticated_service():
    if not os.path.exists(CLIENT_CREDENTIALS_FILE):
        flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(CLIENT_SECRETS_FILE, SCOPES)
        credentials = flow.run_local_server(open_browser=False)
        credentials_json = credentials.to_json().replace('token_uri', 'token_url')
        #print(credentials_json)
        open(CLIENT_CREDENTIALS_FILE, 'wt').write(credentials_json)
    else:
        credentials = external_account_authorized_user.Credentials.from_file(CLIENT_CREDENTIALS_FILE)
    return build(API_SERVICE_NAME, API_VERSION, credentials=credentials)

def initialize_upload(youtube, options):
    tags = None
    if options.keywords:
        tags = options.keywords.split(",")

    body = dict(
        snippet=dict(
            title=options.title,
            description=options.description,
            tags=tags,
            categoryId=options.category,
        ),
        status=dict(privacyStatus=options.privacyStatus),
    )

    insert_request = youtube.videos().insert(
        part=",".join(body.keys()),
        body=body,
        media_body=MediaFileUpload(options.file, chunksize=-1, resumable=True),
    )

    return resumable_upload(insert_request)


# This method implements an exponential backoff strategy to resume a
# failed upload.
def resumable_upload(request):
    response = None
    error = None
    retry = 0
    while response is None:
        try:
            print("Uploading file...")
            status, response = request.next_chunk()
            if response is not None:
                if "id" in response:
                    print('Video id "%s" was successfully uploaded.' % response["id"])
                    return response["id"]
                else:
                    exit("The upload failed with an unexpected response: %s" % response)
        except HttpError as e:
            if e.resp.status in RETRIABLE_STATUS_CODES:
                error = "A retriable HTTP error %d occurred:\n%s" % (
                    e.resp.status,
                    e.content,
                )
            else:
                raise
        except RETRIABLE_EXCEPTIONS as e:
            error = "A retriable error occurred: %s" % e

        if error is not None:
            print(error)
            retry += 1
            if retry > MAX_RETRIES:
                exit("No longer attempting to retry.")

            max_sleep = 2**retry
            sleep_seconds = random.random() * max_sleep
            print("Sleeping %f seconds and then retrying..." % sleep_seconds)
            time.sleep(sleep_seconds)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument("--file", required=True, help="Video file to upload")
    parser.add_argument("--title", help="Video title", default="Test Title")
    parser.add_argument(
        "--description", help="Video description", default="Test Description"
    )
    parser.add_argument(
        "--category",
        default="22",
        help="Numeric video category. "
        + "See https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videoCategories/list",
    )
    parser.add_argument(
        "--keywords", help="Video keywords, comma separated", default=""
    )
    parser.add_argument(
        "--privacyStatus",
        choices=VALID_PRIVACY_STATUSES,
        default="private",
        help="Video privacy status.",
    )
    args = parser.parse_args()

    youtube = get_authenticated_service()

    try:
        video_id = initialize_upload(youtube, args)
    except HttpError as e:
        print("An HTTP error %d occurred:\n%s" % (e.resp.status, e.content))
        pprint.pp(json.loads(e.content))
        video_id = None

    thumbnail_image = f"{args.file}.png"
    if os.path.exists(thumbnail_image) and video_id:
        print("Uploading thumbnail...")
        req = youtube.thumbnails().set(videoId=video_id, media_body=MediaFileUpload(thumbnail_image))
        resp = req.execute()
        if resp['kind'] != 'youtube#thumbnailSetResponse':
            print("ERROR: thumbnail image response:", resp)

Incredibly, Google's examples I've found are for Python 2, so the bulk of the scripts is Google's code adapted for Python 3.

Please edit your question and include your code

@LindaLawton-DaImTo here it is!

Is that even requesting authorization of the user?

Yes it is. The first script does that.
